# Monkey-patching OpenTimelineIO adapter to import Final Cut Pro XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, finalcut

I have several video projects from Final Cut Pro that I want to use in KdenLive. I found the OpenTimelineIO project and it would solve all my problems. I installed with

```bash
$ python3 -m pip install opentimelineio
...
$ python3 -m pip show opentimelineio
Name: OpenTimelineIO
Version: 0.15.0
```

I tried the sample code provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO):

```py
import opentimelineio as otio

timeline = otio.adapters.read_from_file("/path/to/file.fcpxml")
for clip in timeline.find_clips():
  print(clip.name, clip.duration())
```

and I get the error:

```bash
  File "~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 998, in _format_id_for_clip
    resource = self._compound_clip_by_id(
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Following ["AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'" when converting with OpenTimelineIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76725224/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-find-when-converting-with) , I monkey-patch the source code, changing around line 991:

```py
def _format_id_for_clip(self, clip, default_format):
    if not clip.get("ref", None) or clip.tag == "gap":
        return default_format

    resource = self._asset_by_id(clip.get("ref"))

    if resource is None:
        resource = self._compound_clip_by_id(
            clip.get("ref")
        ).find("sequence")
```

To:

```py
def _format_id_for_clip(self, clip, default_format):
    if not clip.get("ref", None) or clip.tag == "gap":
        return default_format

    resource = self._asset_by_id(clip.get("ref"))

    if resource is None:
        resource = self._compound_clip_by_id(
            clip.get("ref")
        )
        if resource is None:
            return default_format
        else:
            resource = resource.find("sequence")

    return resource.get("format", default_format)
```

Then I get another error:

```bash
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 1054, in _format_frame_duration
    total, rate = media_format.get("frameDuration").split("/")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The offending lines are:

```py
# --------------------
# time helpers
# --------------------
def _format_frame_duration(self, format_id):
    media_format = self._format_by_id(format_id)
    total, rate = media_format.get("frameDuration").split("/")
    rate = rate.replace("s", "")
    return total, rate
```

So I printed details on clips, and it seems most are `100/2500s`, so I return that:

```py
def _format_frame_duration(self, format_id):
    media_format = self._format_by_id(format_id)
    print(media_format)
    print(dir(media_format))
    try:
        print(media_format.__dict__)
        print(media_format.__dict__())
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    print([attr for attr in dir(media_format) if attr[:2] + attr[-2:] != '____' and not callable(getattr(media_format,attr))])
    print(media_format.attrib)
    print(media_format.tag)
    print(media_format.tail)
    print(media_format.text)

    if None is media_format.get("frameDuration"):
        return "100", "2500"
    
    total, rate = media_format.get("frameDuration").split("/")
    rate = rate.replace("s", "")
    return total, rate
```

And then that command runs, but the next throws an error:

```bash
    for clip in timeline.find_clips():
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'opentimelineio._otio.SerializableCollection' object has no attribute 'find_clips'
```

I try running the import from Kdenlive and get this error:

```bash
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/fcpx_xml.py", line 938, in _timing_clip
    while clip.tag not in ("clip", "asset-clip", "ref-clip"):
          ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

[Here is a Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7xg18lh4a6ehy9k3f442a/Info.fcpxml?rlkey=v0o9b59lhn1mgl7qxnuw6tzsy&dl=0) to a complete FCP XML file that causes this error.

I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO/issues/1661) on GitHub about the second error that I monkey-patched and it has had no activity for 3 months. These issues raise the bar quite a bit and require some knowledge of opentimelineio, so I ask or help here.

How can I further monkey-patch the OpenTimelineIO code to convert this project to Kdenlive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `.fcpxml` file. When I debug, it throws an error on the format tag with `id="r110"`:

[image]

Other format tags have more attributes like frameDuration, as you mentioned:

[image]

If you know the correct values for this entry, you can add it on line 1256 and change it from:

`<format id="r110" name="FFVideoFormatRateUndefined" width="1920" height="1080"/>`

To something like:

`<format id="r110" name="FFVideoFormatRateUndefined" width="1920" height="1080" frameDuration="100/2500s"/>`

When you fix this, the next error is this:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

When you face this error, the running variables are:

[image]

Which corresponds to the line 3219 of the file:

`<title ref="r120" offset="1848900/7500s" name="© Atletismo Emocional para crianças, 2020 - Scrolling" start="3600s" duration="57300/2500s">`

The error happens because there are no `<asset>` or `<media>` elements with `id="r120"`.

The `r120` reference appears in two tags only, so I removed them and reran the program. This is what to remove:

line 1345 (`effect` tag)
line 3218 to 3387 (`title` tag)
*Lines are approximate*
(If you have any information on what `id` is used for this reference, put it in the `<title>` element, and also you have to create a `<format>` element as I saw the code extracts that too. If you don't have the info, then just remove the tags with `r120`.)

Now it passes that line and throws another error:

`'opentimelineio._otio.SerializableCollection' object has no attribute 'find_clips'`. This is awkward because the problem is with the module itself. The object does not have the method mentioned, and I think the substitution is to use `each_clip().` So, to fix it, you have to change this:

`timeline.find_clips() -> timeline.each_clip()`

This will fix the problem, and it runs without any monkey-patches!

Comment: Yes, that seems to do it, thanks! I'll need to do the same on several other projects: which debugger do you use to show those variables, and where do you break to get the information on those screenshots?

Comment: Indeed, `find_clips` is from a yet-to-be-released version of OpenTimelineIO. I filed an issue and a contributor explained it at: https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO/issues/1694

Comment: @miguelmorin I used VSCode. It usually satisfies any debugging needs I have in Python. I will see it and let you know if I can solve it.

Comment: Thanks @armin, I'll try that. The other question has a bounty that ends today with only one answer that doesn't solve the problem. I believe the bounty will be automatically awarded to it within one day.

Comment: I asked a follow-up question, about failing to import into Kdenlive, and it got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974108/opentimelineio-error-from-exporting-a-final-cut-pro-file-with-the-kdenlive-adapt . I also asked another question, where the FCP adapter couldn't find any of the external clips, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238366/opentimelineio-fcp-xml-import-fails-to-find-clips .

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `find_clips` method incorrectly.The Timeline object does not support the `find_clips` method.

The `find_clips` method is available for the `otio.adapters.Kdenlive` adapter, not for the Timeline object directly. Make sure you are using the adapter correctly.

```
adapter = otio.adapters.Kdenlive()

timeline = adapter.read_from_file(kdenlive_project_file)

for clip in timeline.find_clips():
```

In error it says you are using
opentimelineio library. In code snippet it refers OpenTimelineIO class which belongs to a different library called `opentime`. Make sure you are using the correct library and class names.

Comment: Indeed, `find_clips` is from a yet-to-be-released version of OpenTimelineIO. I filed an issue and a contributor explained it at: https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO/issues/1694