# OpenTimelineIO error from exporting a Final Cut Pro file with the Kdenlive adapter

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, finalcut

Follow-up on [Monkey-patching OpenTimelineIO adapter to import Final Cut Pro XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846715/monkey-patching-opentimelineio-adapter-to-import-final-cut-pro-xml)

I have several video projects from Final Cut Pro that I want to use in KdenLive. I found the OpenTimelineIO project and it would solve all my problems. I installed it, fixed the XML file following the suggestions from the thread above and am able to read with the FCP adapter.

I install `opentimelineio` from the PyPI, run `otioconvert`, and get an error related to the Kdenlive export adapter:

```
 $ otioconvert -i /path/to/file/ep4_fixed.fcpxml -o /path/to/file/ep4_fixed.kdenlive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/otioconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/console/otioconvert.py", line 278, in main
    otio.adapters.write_to_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/__init__.py", line 192, in write_to_file
    return adapter.write_to_file(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/adapter.py", line 192, in write_to_file
    result = self.write_to_string(input_otio, **adapter_argument_map)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/adapter.py", line 283, in write_to_string
    return self._execute_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/plugins/python_plugin.py", line 153, in _execute_function
    return (getattr(self.module(), func_name)(**kwargs))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/kdenlive.py", line 389, in write_to_string
    rate = input_otio.duration().rate
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'opentimelineio._otio.SerializableCollection' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

When I try to import it on Kdenlive, I get the same error:

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/otioconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/console/otioconvert.py", line 278, in main
    otio.adapters.write_to_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/__init__.py", line 192, in write_to_file
    return adapter.write_to_file(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/adapter.py", line 192, in write_to_file
    result = self.write_to_string(input_otio, **adapter_argument_map)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/adapters/adapter.py", line 283, in write_to_string
    return self._execute_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio/plugins/python_plugin.py", line 153, in _execute_function
    return (getattr(self.module(), func_name)(**kwargs))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/opentimelineio_contrib/adapters/kdenlive.py", line 390, in write_to_string
    rate = input_otio.duration().rate
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'opentimelineio._otio.SerializableCollection' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

The error is distinct from that thread in that the offending collection is of this sort:

```
SerializableCollection(ep1-6, [otio.schema.Timeline(name='ep4', tracks=otio.schema.Stack(name='', children=[otio.schema.Track(name='-1', children=[otio.schema.Gap(name='',...
```

How can I tweak the XML file or the source code to fix this error and export for reading in Kdenlive?

The FCP XML file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/92ujpyxo86w56m4qpuh8b/ep4_fixed.fcpxml?rlkey=8kpom8mmebzup9uo67ue2099m&dl=0).

### update

I tried this conversion under two methods.

First, I uninstalled `opentimelineio` (`python3 -m pip uninstaled opentimelineio`) and installed it from PyPI with `python3 -m pip install opentimelineio`. The `kdenlive` adapter is listed:

```py
$ python3 -c "import opentimelineio as otio; print(otio.adapters.available_adapter_names())"
['otio_drp_adapter', 'fcp_xml', 'otio_json', 'otioz', 'otiod', 'cmx_3600', 'svg', 'fcpx_xml', 'hls_playlist', 'rv_session', 'maya_sequencer', 'ale', 'burnins', 'AAF', 'xges', 'kdenlive']
```

When I run `otioconvert`, as above, I get the same error as above (`SerializableCollection` has no attribute `duration`).

Second, I removed that installation and installed it from source, cloning the project from GitHub, from the latest commit of the `main` branch (version `OpenTimelineIO-0.16.0.dev1`, installed with `python3 -m pip install .`). Then, `kdenlive` is not listed as an adapter, and indeed `kdenlive.py` is missing from the directory `contrib/adapters`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if this is similar to [`AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO` issue 1694](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO/issues/1694), which mentions:

> The default `README` is from the tip of the main branch, not the released OTIO. You can see the released one at https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenTimelineIO/tree/v0.15.
>
> So the actual readme is accurate since `find_clips` will be present in a yet to be released OTIO.

So you might need to tweak the OpenTimelineIO version to get the one with `duration` as an attribute.

---

> If I understand correctly, you're suggesting that the version 0.16 will fix the issue.
> I removed OpenTimelineIO installed with `pip` and installed from source from the tip of the main branch, and I get the error `opentimelineio.exceptions.NoKnownAdapterForExtensionError: No adapter for suffix 'kdenlive' on file ...`.
> So I can't yet say whether that version will work.

Make sure the Kdenlive adapter is included in the OpenTimelineIO plugins directory and that it is correctly implemented.
Since you are working with the source code, check the `opentimelineio_contrib/adapters` directory for a `kdenlive.py` file or similar. If you are working with the main branch, it is possible that new adapters or features are in development and not yet fully integrated or documented.

Also, OpenTimelineIO uses a plugin mechanism to discover and register adapters. You can check which adapters are currently recognized by your installation with [`adapters.available_adapter_names()`](https://opentimelineio.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/api/modules/opentimelineio.adapters.html#opentimelineio.adapters.available_adapter_names):

```py
import opentimelineio as otio
print(otio.adapters.available_adapter_names())
```

If 'kdenlive' is not listed, the adapter is not correctly registered, which could be due to it not being included in the source code you have installed or due to an issue with the plugin discovery mechanism.
If the 'kdenlive' adapter is present in the source code but not registered, you might try manually invoking it. That would be a more complex and less recommended approach, given it bypasses the standard adapter mechanisms.

---

> I tried again, from scratch, with the package from PyPI (it has `kdenlive` as an adapter but throws the same error) and from source (it's missing `kdenlive` as an adapter). I searched the GitHub repo for a branch that has both `kdenlive` as an adapter and duration as an attribute for `SerializableCollection`, but couldn't find it.
>
> I'm not fiddling with the source code and trying to access `duration`, I'm only running `otioconvert` on the XML file from Final Cut Pro.

OK, so you mean the adapter is trying to call `duration()` on an object it assumes to be a `Timeline` but is actually a `SerializableCollection`. The adapter should either make sure it is operating on a `Timeline` object or implement logic to handle `SerializableCollection` appropriately.
As a temporary workaround until the adapter issue is resolved, you might consider writing a small script that ensures the input to the `kdenlive` adapter is a `Timeline` object. That would involve loading the `.fcpxml` file, extracting the `Timeline` from the `SerializableCollection` (if necessary), and then saving that as a `.kdenlive` file using the adapter programmatically.

```py
import opentimelineio as otio

# Load the FCP XML file
input_otio = otio.adapters.read_from_file("/path/to/file/ep4_fixed.fcpxml")

# Extract the first Timeline from the SerializableCollection
timeline = next((item for item in input_otio if isinstance(item, otio.schema.Timeline)), None)

if timeline:
    # Save the timeline as a Kdenlive project
    otio.adapters.write_to_file(timeline, "/path/to/file/ep4_fixed.kdenlive", adapter_name="kdenlive")
else:
    print("No timeline found in the input file.")
```

Comment: I filed that issue and `find_clips` was also referred in one solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846715/monkey-patching-opentimelineio-adapter-to-import-final-cut-pro-xml . So I believe this is a separate issue, now touching on the exporter into Kdenlive rather than the importer from FCP.

Comment: @miguelmorin OK. I see your issue was closed because "the mismatch will disappear with the 0.16.0 release." Will that be enough for you?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're suggesting that the version 0.16 will fix the issue. I removed OpenTimelineIO installed with pip and installed from source from the tip of the main branch, and get the error `opentimelineio.exceptions.NoKnownAdapterForExtensionError: No adapter for suffix 'kdenlive' on file ...`. So I can't yet say whether that version will work.

Comment: I tried again, from scratch, with the package from PyPI (it has `kdenlive` as an adapter but throws the same error) and from source (it's missing `kdenlive` as an adapter). I searched the Github repo for a branch that has both `kdenlive` as an adapter and `duration` as an attribute for `SerializableCollection` but couldn't find it. Do you know of one? Shall I file this as a bug in the Github repo?

Comment: @miguelmorin `duration`? `SerializableCollection` is a container for various OTIO objects and does not inherently have timeline properties like `duration`. The `duration` attribute is specific to timeline-related objects (e.g., `Clip`, `Track`, `Timeline`). You would need to extract a `Timeline` object from the collection before attempting to access timeline-specific attributes.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm not fiddling with the source code and trying to access `duration`, I'm only running `otioconvert` on the XML file from Final Cut Pro.

Comment: @miguelmorin OK. I have edited the answer accordingly. You might also have to report to the OpenTimelineIO project's issue tracker on GitHub.

Comment: I could file an issue in the OpenTimelineIO core project, but the template suggests `For adapter related issues, please go to the appropriate repository - likely in
the [OpenTimelineIO github organization](https://github.com/OpenTimelineIO/).` The [list of repositories](https://github.com/orgs/OpenTimelineIO/repositories?type=all) is missing Kdenlive and I found [this repo](https://github.com/KDE/kdenlive-opentimelineio) that apparently will house the Kdenlive adapter, but they aren't accepting issues at the moment. So, for now, your code solves the problem and may hep others. Thanks!

Comment: Now that this works, I am blocked at the next error, that the adapter cannot find any external media, and asked about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78238366/opentimelineio-fcp-xml-import-fails-to-find-clips . Have you faced this issue before?

Comment: @miguelmorin Thank you for the bounty, but you did not have to do that ;) I will check out your next question (no bounty needed, this time).